# LiveAgent "No version header found" in API version 30

Tags: api

With the update from API version 29 to 30 our test chat button is now returning the error msg "No Version header found".

What changed from Version 29 to 30?

Thanks, Frank

Answer (score 1):

Check the the header parameter it should be "X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION"